# /usr/lib/python37.zip in sys.path

Tags: python-3.x, sys.path, debian-buster

Just had a quick check on `sys.path` of `python 3.7` on Debian Buster:

```
qxu@debian:~$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))

/usr/lib/python37.zip
/usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
>>>
```

Each entry looks good, except for the first one:

```
qxu@debian:~$ ll /usr/lib/python37.zip
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python37.zip': No such file or directory
```

I am not sure why the zip file itself could be part of `sys.path`. Shouldn't `sys.path` only include directories?

Even if there is a reason for the zip file to be part of `sys.path`, why couldn't it be located physically?

Comment: Maybe duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822593/why-does-sys-path-have-c-windows-system-python34-zip